# Can I pass server actions as props to client components if they are doing mutations?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, react-server-components

The docs on sever action have this line:

> If you aren't doing [Server Mutations](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions#server-mutations), you can directly pass the function as a prop like any other function.
> Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions#custom-invocation-without-starttransition

My question:

Why does this depend on the mutation? Is it okay to pass server actions from server components to client components even if the action contains a mutation and calls `revalidatePath`? I need to do this because right now, Next-auth's `getServerSession` cannot be called in server actions directly imported into client components.

Another question related to this: Why am I getting this lint warning when I try to pass a server action to a client component? It works at runtime:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass server actions to client components. Make sure to add ‘use server’ at the top of the server action and make sure it is an asynchronous function. Then import it in the client component using ‘use client’ at the beginning of the file. To call the server action in the client component, wrap it in an asynchronous function as well and add ‘await’ before the server action function.

Regarding the error, you need to make the props serializable. Turn the setProductQuantity props into a singular object, not different parameters.

This question was answered [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/147jk2m/comment/jo07xfo/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) by bullettrain1